# Current, previous and next KB for SharePoint

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-administration, kb-update

Is it possible to know the latest KB (Security update & SP), the previous KB and next KB that has been installed on the server ?

I face difficulty to understand because it is not in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at Programs and Features -> View installed updates in the Control Panel on each Windows server for what updates have been applied and when.

Answer (score 0):

I find this blog post from Stefan very useful in understanding. He has similar articles around patching SharePoint environments.

[Finding the right Patch Number - Stefan Blog](https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2016/08/23/sharepoint-does-not-have-a-build-version-full-stop/)

> To quote : We have seen that the only reliable source to check if a specific patch has been installed is the “Manage Patch Status” page in the Central admin. Even this page does not directly expose to you if all fixes in a specific CU have been installed. It is required to check all the components individually.
>
> The learning is that there is no single version number in SharePoint
>   which would reliably tell you the patch level for a server or a server
>   farm.
>
> If you are facing the challenge to determine if your server is has
>   specific fixes installed you should start with the Windows Control
>   Panel / Programs and Features which will list all the fixes installed
>   on the box and on top the “Manage Patch Status” page in the Central
>   admin to verify the patch status on the different servers.

Answer (score 0):

You could go to CA-> Upgrade and Migration-> Check product and installation status, you would see the details there.

Answer (score 0):

To check the CU on your server you need to follow below mentioned steps.

1. Navigate to the control panel  and select **Programs** from the panel.
   [image]
2. Select the View installed updates and all KB articles will start showing up .
   [image]

For tracking,you can compare the dates and accordingly you will know the older and newer updates.